# How to get all values from a database column

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have a basic system I am creating in which a user creates goals. When the goal is inserted, it is given a value of 0 to the `status` column. When the goal is completed, the value is updated to 1. So, what I am trying to do is fetch the specific user's (user with the current session) total number of ids (rows for the amount of goals) and then get the values of the `status` column and then count those. Once the actual `status` column values have been added, I want to divide that by the total number of id's. I am basically trying to figure out how to get a rate of completion.

I am not certain how I can:

-count the number of total id's for the user.
-get the values of the `status` column for the user and then add those.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
Table
Create Table
goals
CREATE TABLE `goals` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `title` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `status` int(5) NOT NULL,
 `importance` int(5) NOT NULL,
 `date` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_c


$select_goals_sql = "
    SELECT *
    FROM goals
    WHERE user_id = ?
    ORDER BY id DESC    
";

if ($select_goals_stmt = $con->prepare($select_goals_sql)) {
    $select_goals_stmt->execute(array($user_id));
    $rows = $select_goals_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $goals = array();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $goal_date = $row['date'];
        $fixed_goal_date = fixDate($goal_date);
        // the varialbe I will name it $status_completed = 
        $html = "";
```

Edit:

```
$goal_total_sql = "
        SELECT sum(status) as sumna, 
        COUNT(*) as cnt 
        FROM goals
        WHERE user_id = ?
    ";

    if ($goal_total_stmt = $con->prepare($goal_total_sql)) {
        $goal_total_stmt->execute(array($user_id));
        $rows = $goal_total_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $actual_status = $row['status'];
            $total_status = $row['id'];
        }   
    }
?>
    <div id="main">
    <?php
    echo "Actual:". $actual_status;
    echo "Total". $total_status;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT status_id FROM goals WHERE userId = ? GROUP BY status_id` should count the number of ids for each state

Answer (score -1):

I's hard to tell what you need here because the question title contradicts with body and both with code provided. But as far as I can tell

```
SELECT sum(status) as summa, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM ...
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if there was a way that PHP could do this without having to create another query., since I was already making a connection to the database in question. Your query gets the completion rate, but is there anyway to get the completion rate and then get the invidual, total number of id's and `status`'s with one as the value, or will I need to make another query for those as well?

Comment: I see you made an edit. How am I able to execute those into variables since it is defined into the query?

Comment: I just edited my question to show what I am doing. The variables are undefined, but whenever I add the foreach back and extend the closing brackets past the echoes, it turns the page blank.

Comment: It order to get the selected values you need to learn basic PDO.

Comment: Are you expressing this because of the commented out foreach? I have no idea how to call for the rows based on the query you made. I am trying to learn. If I change the foreach to this, I get the same response. `foreach ($rows as $row) {
   $actual_status = $row['status'];
   $total_status = $row['id'];
  }`

Comment: summa and cnt are the field names that you selected.

Comment: How? I changed them to unknown values with ?. Not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: DO NOT change the query. it already has everything you need. just get thee two selected columns USUAL WAY, just like you do it for any other PDO query.

Comment: Well I need the WHERE argument to only get it for the current user. I updated my question again with my current code. I am getting a 0 paramaters, 1 parameter given error, which makes no sense because I am not declaring the value of user_id in my query.

Comment: summa and cnt are the field names that you selected.

Comment: Yes, because i am wanting to display those results... Is this just totally going over my head or what?

Comment: so display *them*. why you're constantly trying to display whatever else values is beyond my understanding

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as goal_count, status FROM goals WHERE user_id = ? GROUP BY status;
```

This will show you in tabular format the goal_count next to the status.

here is a sqlfiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1bb23

so using a modified version of your create table (You should be using Innodb and I ommited the Collac for simplicity)

your result should be like this:

```
+------------+--------+                                                                                                                                                                                             
| goal_count | status |                                                                                                                                                                                             
+------------+--------+                                                                                                                                                                                             
|          1 |      1 |                                                                                                                                                                                             
|          2 |      2 |                                                                                                                                                                                             
|          2 |      3 |                                                                                                                                                                                             
|          2 |      4 |                                                                                                                                                                                             
+------------+--------+
```